# how to get all combinations from a array reaching a certain number?

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

I am trying to get al the combinations that at least reaches 100. If you add one to another so 10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10(100)>= 100, but also 20+20+20+20+10+15(105)>=100. But right now it only shows a few because I don't know how i can let him show every possible combination.

I use a for loop in a while so it'll add till the 'GETALTEBEREIKEN' is exceded. but than it'll just check after all is added. And even if it is added i dont get ever 10*10. Because it'll just go to the next number in the array. So it doesn't give me all combinations.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int TOTAALGETALLEN = 3;
        const int GETALTEBEREIEKEN = 100;
        int[] Getallen = new int[TOTAALGETALLEN];
        Getallen[0] = 10;
        Getallen[1] = 15;
        Getallen[2] = 20;
        int totaal = 0;
        string GebruikteGetallen;

        for(int i = 0; i < TOTAALGETALLEN; i++)
        {
            totaal = Getallen[i];
            GebruikteGetallen = i + ", ";
            while (totaal<GETALTEBEREIEKEN)
            {

                for(int j = 0; j < TOTAALGETALLEN; j++)
                {
                    totaal += Getallen[j];
                    GebruikteGetallen += j + ", ";
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(GebruikteGetallen);
            Console.WriteLine(totaal);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();  
    }
```

it should subsets (combinations of elements of a set) that fulfill a criterion.

I also found this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] set = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        foreach (string s in GetCombinations(set, 18, ""))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(int[] set, int sum, string values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < set.Length; i++)
        {
            int left = sum - set[i];
            string vals = set[i] + "," + values;
            if (left == 0)
            {
                yield return vals;
            }
            else
            {
                int[] possible = set.Take(i).Where(n => n <= sum).ToArray();
                if (possible.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string s in GetCombinations(possible, left, vals))
                    {
                        yield return s;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this wont let me use the same Number once again. Maybe it will help with your answer.

Comment: Questions seeking help with some school project are usually not welcome here. I'd suggest you to ask help from your teacher.

Comment: What is the project supposed to do and what does it do?

Comment: @RobAnthony i need to see what possible combinations are possible, its okay if it exceeds 100 but if it is already over 100 and you ad some more like another 10 you'll get 110, that will only 'Cost' more. In the end every Getal in Getallen will get his own 'Cost', which is why i need to know what numbers are used. So i can calculate what would be the cheapest option.

Comment: Actually, if a question is clear, if it shows there has been some attempt to answer it, I don't think there is an issue why the question is asked - school project questions are not purely by definition unwelcome. It's when the question just gets dumped here with no attempt at an answer that it's unwelcome. I think this question needs editing to make it clearer what its trying to do and what currently goes wrong though.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking for.
Do you want all different combinations of 10 15 and 20 that reach atleast 100?

Comment: @horotab i want every different combination so 20*5=100 is one 15*7=105 is one 10*10=100 is one, but also the combinations so 20*4+10*2=100, 20*4+15*2=110, 20+15*6=110, 15*2+10*7=100, and so on.

Comment: Ok I think I get it.
Another question to be clear:
20 + 20 + 20 + 20 + 15 + 15 = 4 * 20 = 2 * 15 = 110
20 + 20 + 20 + 15 + 15 + 20 = 4 * 20 = 2 * 15 = 110
The order is different but its both 4 * 20 and 2 * 15. Are they the same or does the order matter?

Comment: @horotab No order doesnt matter, they are the same, although if you could help me and it does duplicate(maybe in a different order) thats fine too. I know it will take more time to process.

Comment: Do you have exactly these three (10, 15, 20) or is it just an example and should work with any number of numbers?

Comment: @horotab It's just an example i should be able to change the number to work with and the number tot reach, hopefully even change the quantity of numbers in the array.

Comment: Why do you want EVERY combination? Is this the end result or are you doing another calculation after that?

Comment: @RobAnthony Yes there is going to be another calculation which i can make with the answer of every combination, order doesnt matter. The next calculation will be the same for a different order. Example 10 costs 7, 15 costs 17, 20 costs 23. I'll check with every combination the costs and chooses the cheapest.

Comment: I will see if I can give you some help.

Comment: @horotab Thank you in advance!

Comment: @horotab I just added something, might help you but wont let me use the same number again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I have written a program to solve this.

Since you want to be variable I have used recursion instead of stacked loops.
I also added many comments to make it easier to understand how it works.
If you have the correct solution please check if the result is fine.

```
internal class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        // these are the same numbers, but you can replace or add some
        const int limit = 100;
        // if you don't know what a dictionary does you should google that
        var resources = new Dictionary<Good, int>();
        // this is the price of the resource
        resources[Good.Copper] = 20;
        resources[Good.Tin] = 15;
        resources[Good.Iron] = 10;
        //resources[Good.Paper] = 8;
        //resources[Good.Plastic] = 6;
        //resources[Good.Water] = 2;

        // Now we want to calculate all possible combinations.
        // We can not just put some loops into each other because when we have 4 instead of 3 resources we would need 4 loops.
        // Instead we will use some concept called recursion.

        // First we sort the resources from expensive to cheap
        var sortedResources = resources.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);
        // all combinations will be stored in here
        var allSolutions = new List<List<KeyValuePair<Good, int>>>();
        // We will start with the maximum amount of the most expensive good and then lower its amount and check all amount of the other goods.

        var calculator = new CombinationCalculator(limit, sortedResources.ToList(), allSolutions);
        calculator.CalculateCombinationsRecursive(0, 0, new List<KeyValuePair<Good, int>>());
        Console.WriteLine("\nAll solutions calculated, " + allSolutions.Count + " combinations found.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This are the different resources

```
internal enum Good {
    Copper = 1,
    Tin = 2,
    Iron = 3,
    Paper = 4,
    Plastic = 5,
    Water = 6
}
```

This class is calculating the combinations.

```
internal class CombinationCalculator {
    private readonly List<List<KeyValuePair<Good, int>>> _allSolutions;
    private readonly int _limit;
    private readonly List<KeyValuePair<Good, int>> _sortedResources;


    /// <summary>
    ///     This class will calculate all combinations
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="limit">The minimum cost (100 for example)</param>
    /// <param name="sortedResources">All resources and their individual price sorted descending.</param>
    /// <param name="allSolutions">all completed combinations of resources and each amount.</param>
    public CombinationCalculator(int limit, List<KeyValuePair<Good, int>> sortedResources, List<List<KeyValuePair<Good, int>>> allSolutions) {
        _limit = limit;
        _sortedResources = sortedResources;
        _allSolutions = allSolutions;
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Find all combinations recursive.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The resource that should be added next.</param>
    /// <param name="currentPrice">The price what the resources that are already added cost.</param>
    /// <param name="resources">All resources that are already added and their amount.</param>
    internal void CalculateCombinationsRecursive(int index, int currentPrice, List<KeyValuePair<Good, int>> resources) {
        // we calculate the amount af this resource needed to get atleast the limit
        var maximumAmount = (int)Math.Ceiling((_limit - currentPrice) / (1.0 * _sortedResources[index].Value));

        // with maximum amount you have one combination already
        var firstCombi = resources.ToList();
        firstCombi.Add(new KeyValuePair<Good, int>(_sortedResources[index].Key, maximumAmount));
        Console.WriteLine("Found one combination: ");
        foreach(var res in firstCombi) {
            Console.Write(" " + res.Key + " * " + res.Value + ",");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" price: " + (currentPrice + maximumAmount * _sortedResources[index].Value));
        _allSolutions.Add(firstCombi);

        // if this is already the last resource we can't add more
        if(index == _sortedResources.Count - 1) {
            return;
        }
        // now find all other possible combinations recursive
        for(var i = maximumAmount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // since we add less than maximum amount we will need to fill the price with the other resources
            var newResources = resources.ToList();
            newResources.Add(new KeyValuePair<Good, int>(_sortedResources[index].Key, i));
            // this method calls itself recursive
            CalculateCombinationsRecursive(index + 1, currentPrice + i * _sortedResources[index].Value, newResources);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have questions feel free to ask.

I hope this is useful for you, if you want to test other stuff just modify the first part of the main method and the enum.

Comment: OMG you are officially my hero! This worked like i hope it worked. I could even make the changes to let it totaly work with al the things i wanted it to work with! insane! Thanks you so much!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.